# After using fgetc(stdin) on a variable, how do I pass the input to strtol?

Tags: c, strtol

I have a variable where the user inputs one number. That variable is of type `int` because that's the return value of `fgetc(stdin)` and `getchar()`. In this case, I'm using `fgetc(stdin)`. After the user inputs the number, I would like to convert it to an integer with `strtol()`, however, I get a warning about an incompatible integer to pointer conversion because of `strtol()`'s first argument being a `const char *`. Here is the code:

```
int option;
char *endptr;
int8_t choice;

printf("=========================================Login or Create Account=========================================\n\n");
while(1) {
    printf("Welcome to the Bank management program! Would you like to 1. Create Account or 2. Login?\n>>> ");
    fflush(stdout);
    option = fgetc(stdin);
    choice = strtol(option, &endptr, 10);
```

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtol` is used to convert a "string" into `long`, not a single char. You just need `choice = option - '0'` to get the value. But you don't actually need to convert because you can directly switch on the char value

```
switch (option)
{
    case '1':
        // ...
        break;
    case '2':
        // ...
        break;
}
```

If you really want to call `strtol` then you must make a string

```
char[2] str;
str[0] = option;
str[1] = 0; // null terminator
choice = strtol(str, &endptr, 10);
```

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. I'll go ahead and do that. But let's say I did want to turn it into an `int`, would it be possible without getting any warnings?

Comment: the warning is there because it's wrong and your code won't work. But yes, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

since the variable 'option' is already an integer, there is no reason to call 'strtol' anymore.

or you can used gets to get a buffer from stdin, then transform the buffer into integer by strtol.